# PowerCli Script for automating Power Replication jobs

Tags: powershell, powercli

I am looking for a script which will do replication using VRA for a big VMFarm (Version5.5) which has around 50k ++  RHEL/Centos/Windows (multiple versions).

Also i am planning to do migration of a small portion using VMconverter.

Can anyone help in this regard.

Regards,
Hari

Comment: I am somewhat worried that you are supposed to be managing fifty *thousand* VMs - and post such questions to SO. ServerFault would be more on topic, but...

Answer (score 0):

For managing there is a team, but currently we ate planning to move this environment to a private cloud, that's where this thing came up, I know the automation up to some extent like creation of VMS, reporting but replication is it new to me, even if know how to for 1 machine, I can script rest of the things...

Thanks